# Normal mapping working incorrectly, weird half-light effect

Tags: c++, glsl, rendering, light, normals

We are trying to implement normal mapping in our 2D Game Engine and get weird effect.
If normal is set manually like that 
`vec3 Normal = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` light works correctly, but we dont get "deep" effect that we want to achieve by normal mapping:
[image]
But if we get normal using normal map texture: `vec3 Normal = texture(NormalMap, TexCoord).rgb` it doesn't work at all. What should not be illuminated is illuminated and vice versa (such as the gaps between the bricks). And besides this, a dark area is on the bottom (or top, depending on the position of the light) side of the texture.
[image]
Although the texture of the normal map itself looks fine:
[image]
This is our fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;
in vec2 FragPos;

uniform sampler2D OurTexture;
uniform sampler2D NormalMap;

struct point_light
{
    vec3 Position;
    vec3 Color;
};

uniform point_light Light;

void main()
{
    vec4 Color = texture(OurTexture, TexCoord);
    vec3 Normal = texture(NormalMap, TexCoord).rgb;

    if (Color.a < 0.1)
        discard;

    vec3 LightDir = vec3(Light.Position.xy - FragPos, Light.Position.z);

    float D = length(LightDir);

    vec3 L = normalize(LightDir);
    Normal = normalize(Normal * 2.0 - 1.0);

    vec3 Diffuse = Light.Color * max(dot(Normal, L), 0);
    vec3 Ambient = vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);

    vec3 Falloff = vec3(1, 0, 0);

    float Attenuation = 1.0 /(Falloff.x + Falloff.y*D + Falloff.z*D*D);
    vec3 Intensity = (Ambient + Diffuse) * Attenuation;

    FragColor = Color * vec4(Intensity, 1);
}
```

And vertex as well:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

uniform mat4 Transform;
uniform mat4 ViewProjection;

out vec2 FragPos;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = ViewProjection * Transform * vec4(aPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
    FragPos = vec2(Transform * vec4(aPosition, 0.0, 1.0));
}
```

I google about that and found some people that get the same result, but their questions remained unanswered.
Any idea of what is the cause?

Comment: What does `Normal = normalize(Normal * 2.0 - 1.0);`? Is it allowed subtracting scalar from Vec3? And what is the effect when you comment this line out?

Comment: @Rixment:Yes.While normal vectors are geometric entities and textures are generally only used for color information. Here we reverse the process of mapping normals to RGB colors by remapping the sampled normal color from [0,1] back to [-1,1] and then use the sampled normal vectors for the upcoming lighting calculations.

Comment: @Rixment Please don't confuse other users. Of course it is allowed in [GLSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language)

Comment: @Rabbid76 I always thought it's not allowed that's why I've asked. What's the result of this operation if I may ask?

Comment: @Rixment In glsl all operations a processed componentwise.

Comment: @Rixment One operand is a scalar, and the other is a vector or matrix. In this case, the scalar operation is applied independently to each component of the vector or matrix, resulting in the same size vector or matrix.

Comment: The issue seems to be related to the light position and attenuation. Remove the attenuation and compare the results (`vec3 Intensity = (Ambient + Diffuse);`)

Comment: @Rabbid76 The same effect. The light itself has become darker. I edited the post and attached the screen.

Comment: And what happen when you rotate your LightDir during rendering?

Comment: @Rixment We don't have rotation yet. But actually nothing should happen. You just change direction of the light.

Comment: Do you have vertex shader as well, maybe I can built it on my machine to check it out.

Comment: @Rixment You can check it out right after fragment shader.

Comment: I'm having some problems building the source in Unity. As for now I would only concentrate on `vec3 Diffuse = Light.Color * max(dot(Normal, L), 0);` leaving the rest of the fragment code commented, as this the part of code is essential to have your desired effect. Also I've noticed that you're computing directional lighting yourself, can you explain the following as I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve `vec3 LightDir = vec3(Light.Position.xy - FragPos, Light.Position.z);`? Shouldn't it be `vec3 LightDir = normalize(fragPos - Light.Position);` ?

Comment: I took a look at your Vertex program, what FragPos represents? It is getting a bit complicated.

Comment: Also could you instead of `vec3 LightDir = vec3(Light.Position.xy - FragPos, Light.Position.z);` assign an arbitrary vec3, for ex (1,1,0) and see what effect it will make?

Comment: @Rixment Answering your first question `vec3 LightDir = vec3(Light.Position.xy - FragPos, Light.Position.z)` This line is needed to determine the direction of light. As I said before, we have a 2D engine, so the position of the fragment is two-dimensional but the normals work only for three-dimensional vectors. Therefore, we calculate the direction of light in two-dimensional space(x,y), and we set z manually using uniforms(Light.Position.z).

Comment: @Rixment If we arbitrary assign `LightDir` to `vec3(1, 0, 0)` there will be no light at all. Because the coordinate space of objects on the screen and the coordinate space of light will diverge

Comment: I've noticed you've made some progress with the issue as it started to render something, am I right? If you want for the parts that should be darker, be lighter and vice versa why wont you change the light source at a negative Z as in `vec3 LightDir = vec3(Light.Position.xy - FragPos, -Light.Position.z);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What texture format are you using for the normal map? SRGB, SNORM, etc? That might be the issue. Try UNORM.

Additionally, since you are not using a tangent space, make sure the plane's Z axis aligns with the Z axis of the normals. Also OGL reads Y in the reversed direction, so you need to flip the Y coordinates of the normals that you read from the normal map. Alternatively, you can use a reversed Y normal map (green pointing down).

Comment: I completely rewrote texture loader and now it works correctly. I still can’t understand how a wrong texture format can give such a WEIRD effect. Moreover, the texture itself looked fine but lighting calculations were wrong. So anyway, changing format from SRGB/SRGBA to RGB/RGBA fixed my problem.

Comment: That was because using SRGB formats does a gamma correction when the texture is loaded, which you do not want for normal maps. You should only use SRGB formats for RGB color textures that will be used as rendering output in the shader.